# Symfony3 error with ManyToMany with attributes

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, many-to-many, symfony-3.3

We have an error when trying to create a relationship within 2 tables like this

Llamadas -||--|<- LlamadaDerivada ->|--||- PersonaDerivada

And we are trying to create an only one create form with the "LlamadaDerivada" into it.

Inside Llamada entity

```
<?php

namespace xxxxBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

class Llamada {

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="SEQUENCE")
     * @ORM\SequenceGenerator(sequenceName="llamada_id_seq", allocationSize=1, initialValue=1)
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @Assert\Length(
     *      max = 50,
     *      maxMessage = "Your first name cannot be longer than {{ limit }} characters",
     * )
     * @ORM\Column(name="nombre", type="string", length=150, nullable=false)
     */
    private $nombre;
    /**
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="LlamadaDerivado", mappedBy="llamada")
     */
    private $derivados;

    function __construct() {
        $this->derivados = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    function getNombre() {
        return $this->nombre;
    }

    function setId($id) {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    function setNombre($nombre) {
        $this->nombre = $nombre;
    }

    function getDerivados(){
        return $this->derivados;
    }
    function setDerivados($derivados){
        $this->derivados = $derivados;
    }
}
```

Then inside LlamadaDerivado Entity we have this

```
<?php

namespace xxxBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * LlamadaDerivado
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="llamada_derivado")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class LlamadaDerivado
{   

    /**
     * @var \AgendaBundle\Entity\Llamada
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AgendaBundle\Entity\Llamada",inversedBy="derivados",cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_llamada", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $llamada;

    /**
     * @var \AgendaBundle\Entity\PersonaDerivado
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AgendaBundle\Entity\PersonaDerivado",inversedBy="llamadas",cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_derivado", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $derivado;


    /**
     * @var DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="fecha_derivacion", type="date", nullable=false)
     */
    private $fechaDerivacion;


    function getLlamada(){
        return $this->llamada;
    }

    function getDerivado(){
        return $this->derivado;
    }

    function getFechaDerivacion() {
        return $this->fechaDerivacion;
    }

    function setLlamada( $llamada) {
        $this->llamada = $llamada;
    }

    function setDerivado( $derivado) {
        $this->derivado = $derivado;
    }

    function setFechaDerivacion($fechaDerivacion) {
        $this->fechaDerivacion = $fechaDerivacion;
    }

}
```

And inside PersonaDerivado entity

```
<?php

namespace xxxBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * ReunionLugar
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="persona_derivado")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class PersonaDerivado
{   

    public function __construct() {
        $this->llamadas = new ArrayCollection();
    }
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="SEQUENCE")
     * @ORM\SequenceGenerator(sequenceName="reunion_lugar_id_seq", allocationSize=1, initialValue=1)
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="nombre", type="string", length=150, nullable=false)
     */
    private $nombre;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="LlamadaDerivado", mappedBy="derivado")
     */
    private $llamadas;

    function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    function getNombre() {
        return $this->nombre;
    }

    function setId($id) {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    function setNombre($nombre) {
        $this->nombre = $nombre;
    }

    function setLlamadas($llamadas) {
        $this->llamadas = $llamadas;
    }

}
```

And the LlamadaType is

```
class LlamadaDto extends AbstractType {

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $disabled = $options['disabled'];


        $builder
                ->add('id', HiddenType::class)
                ->add('nombre', TextType::class, array(
                    'disabled' => $disabled,
                    'attr' => ['maxlength'=>'50']
                ))->add('apellido', TextType::class, array(
                    'disabled' => $disabled,
                    'attr' => ['maxlength'=>'50']
                ))->add('fecha', DateType::class, array(
                    'format' => 'dd/MM/yyyy',
                    'disabled' => $disabled,
                    'widget' => 'single_text',
                    'attr' => ['class' => 'datepicker']
                ))->add('hora', TimeType::class, array(
                    'disabled' => $disabled
                ))->add('motivo', TextareaType::class, array(
                    'disabled' => $disabled,
                    'attr' => ['maxlength'=>'400']
                ))->add('telefonoContacto', TextType::class, array(
                    'disabled' => $disabled,
                    'attr' => ['maxlength'=>'9']
                ))->add('derivados', EntityType::class, array(
                    'class' => 'AgendaBundle:PersonaDerivado',
                    'choice_label' => 'apellidoNombre',
                    'placeholder' => 'Seleccionar un derivado',
                    'multiple' => true,
                ));
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver$resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array('data_class' => Llamada::class));
    }

}
```

Inside the controller we have this code

```
<?php

/**
     * @Route("/Llamada/save",name="saveLlamada")
     */
    public function saveLlamadaAction(Request $request) {
        $llamadaService = $this->get('llamadaService');
        $derivadoService = $this->get('derivadoService');

        $form = $this->createForm(LlamadaDto::class);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        $editar = TRUE;
        $llamada = $form->getData();

        $derivados = $request->request->get("llamada_dto")["derivados"];


        $derivadosActuales = $derivadoService->getLlamadaDerivados($llamada->getId());

        foreach ($derivados as $key1 => $d) {
            foreach ($derivadosActuales as $key2 => $da) {
                if($da->getDerivado()->getId()==$d){
                    array_splice($derivados, array_search($d, $derivados),1);
                }
            }
        }

        if ($llamadaService->saveLlamada($llamada)) {
            $this->addFlash(
                    'exitoLlamada', 'Datos de llamada guardados exitosamente'
            );

            $derivadoService->saveDerivados($derivados,$llamada);
        } else {
            $this->addFlash(
                    'errorLlamada', 'Disculpe, hubo un error en el registro de la llamada'
            );
        }
        return new RedirectResponse($this->generateUrl('listaLlamadas', array(), UrlGeneratorInterface::RELATIVE_PATH));
    }
```

And the services called are this ones:

```
public function saveLlamada($llamada ){
    try{
    if($llamada->getId()){
        $this->em->merge($llamada);
    }else{
        $this->em->persist($llamada);
    }

    $this->em->flush();
    return TRUE;
    } catch (Exception $ex){
        return FALSE;
    }
}

public function saveDerivados($derivados,$llamada){
    foreach ($derivados as $key => $derivado) {
        $llamadaDerivado = new LlamadaDerivado();
        $personaLlamada = $this->getDerivado($derivado);

        $llamadaDerivado->setLlamada($llamada);
        $llamadaDerivado->setDerivado($personaLlamada);
        $llamadaDerivado->setFechaDerivacion(new \DateTime('now', (new \DateTimeZone('America/Argentina/Ushuaia'))));
        $this->em->persist($llamadaDerivado);
        $this->em->flush();
    }
}
```

This is the error that we are getting:

> Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\ORM\ORMInvalidArgumentException: "Expected value of type "Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection|array" for association field "xxxBundle\Entity\Llamada#$derivados", got "xxxBundle\Entity\PersonaDerivado" instead." at project\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\ORMInvalidArgumentException.php line 206

We've been 1 week with this.
Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

look at Llamada entity, $derivados is an array collection of LlamadaDerivado and in your LlamadaType you make it entityType of AgendaBundle:PersonaDerivado, that is why you got this error. Think to use Collection Type to add everytime all the object LlamadaDerivado to well respect the mapping.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I tried to do that, but the problem is that when I do that, only load the entities that I have in the relation, and I need that the option list show all the avalaibles "personaDerivada".

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use a [CollectionType](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html) instead of EntityType in your formtype, although I have a piece of code in front of me that works just fine with EntityType and the `multiple` flag for a OneToMany relationship.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I tried to do that, but the problem is that when I do that, only load the entities that I have in the relation, and I need that the option list show all the avalaibles "personaDerivada".